# Tomcat Logging Issue

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I have configure the console to display finer messages but only severe and info message are out. The rest of the messages like fine, config, finer are unable to display.

Anyone can provide help?

The output

```
29-Aug-2018 18:55:34.918 INFO [http-nio-7080-exec-1] org.apache.jsp.a_jsp._jspService INFO...
29-Aug-2018 18:55:34.922 SEVERE [http-nio-7080-exec-1] org.apache.jsp.a_jsp._jspService SEVERE
```

JSP

```
<%! org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("JSPname"); 
    java.util.logging.Logger LOG = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("simple logger");
%>

<% log.info("Hello Logging!"); %>

<%
LOG.log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, "INFO...");
LOG.log(java.util.logging.Level.FINE, "FINE");
LOG.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, "SEVERE");
LOG.log(java.util.logging.Level.CONFIG, "CONFIG");
LOG.log(java.util.logging.Level.FINER, "FINER");
%>
```

The logging.properties

```
  1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINER
    1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
    1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
    1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90

    2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINER
    2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
    2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.
    2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90

    3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINER
    3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
    3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.
    3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90

    4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINER
    4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
    4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
    4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90

    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINER
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing only INFO and SEVERE is normal.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Extract :

> It can be noted, though, that in Apache Tomcat implementation the
>   calls to ServletContext.log(String) or GenericServlet.log(String) are
>   logged at the INFO level. The calls to ServletContext.log(String,
>   Throwable) or GenericServlet.log(String, Throwable) are logged at the
>   SEVERE level.

Honestly you should try to use external API like log4j.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j

Comment: i am using this logging for application that does not log anything except run time error message only if exist for production. don't think any reason for using log4j and tomcat logging is a lightweight version

Answer (score 0):

anyway when i add this line it works to display all type of messages
.level = FINER